# Delay before the file transfer on Linux or Solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, transfer, delay

I would like to put delay before file transfer on Linux or Solaris.

As far as i know scp commands has no delay option.

```
scp file_name root@dest_ip:/dest_path
```

So, how can i put delay (it can change between 250ms and 500ms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are looking to delay just this one call or are you trying to delay each file from the remote directory?

For one call you can use: 
scp file_name root@dest_ip:/dest_path (for f in `seq 1 10`; do sleep 0.5; done)